# stacked bar chart of percentages by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar chart with the following data

```
fac <- c("A","A","B","B","A","A")
test1 <- c(1,2,1,1,1,3)
test2 <- c(2,1,3,3,3,1)
test3 <- c(1,1,2,2,3,2)
df <- data.frame(fac,test1,test2,test3)
```

I would like to create two charts (for group A and B in "fac")

each chart will have the percentage on the y-axis and the tests (test1,2,3) on the x-axis and will show the proportion of 1's, 2's and 3's for each test.

So for example, for the chart for group A there will be three bars, each will fill 100%, the first bar will be for test1 and will have the percentage of 1's for test1 in group A (in this case 2/4 1's), the percentage of 2's will be 1/4 and the percentage of 3's will be 1/4)

Hope that makes sense, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try

```
 library(reshape2)
 library(ggplot2)
 dfA <- subset(df, fac=='A', select=-1)
 mA <- melt(do.call(cbind,lapply(dfA, function(x) 
       100*prop.table(table(factor(x, levels=1:3))))))
 mA$Var1 <-factor(mA$Var1)

 ggplot(mA, aes(x=Var2, y=value, fill=Var1))+
                                    geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Similarly for `B`

```
 dfB <- subset(df, fac=='B', select=-1)
 mB <- melt(do.call(cbind,lapply(dfB, function(x) 
         100*prop.table(table(factor(x, levels=1:3))))))
 mB$Var1 <-factor(mB$Var1)

 ggplot(mB, aes(x=Var2, y=value, fill=Var1))+
                                 geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

#### Update

If you want both on the same page

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 df1 <- df %>% 
        gather(Var, Val, -fac) %>%
        group_by(fac, Var, Val) %>% 
        summarise(n=n())%>% 
        group_by(fac,Var) %>%
        mutate(n=100*n/sum(n), Val=factor(Val, levels=1:3)) 

 ggplot(df1, aes(x=Var, y=n, fill=Val))+
                geom_bar(stat='identity')+
                facet_wrap(~fac, scales='free')
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `ggplot` does not respect the grouping implied by facets when aggregating functions are used in `aes(...)`. So in your specific case, where you want percentages by test number and also by group (`fac`), we have calculate these outside of `ggplot`. Here is one way using data.tables.

```
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
gg <- melt(df,id="fac")
setkey(setDT(gg),fac,variable,value)
gg <- gg[,list(count=.N),by=list(variable,fac,value)]
gg[,pct:=count/sum(count),by=list(variable,fac)]
ggplot(gg,aes(x=variable, y=pct))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(value)),stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_discrete("value")+
  facet_wrap(~fac) + theme(axis.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

So here we use `melt(...)` to convert your `df` from "wide" format (tests in different columns) to "long" format (all the test values in on column, `value`, with a second column, `variable` distinguishing between tests). Then we convert the result to a data.table and sort by `fac, variable, and value`. Now we count the number of instances of each value, and then divide by the sum of the counts to get percentages. Then we use this data.table to drive `gggplot`.